# HTML Canvas, JavaScript and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to move stars with Selenium on this page:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/labs/html5_canvas_elastic_stars/

They are on html canvas. So if I try to inspect element, I only see canvas tag.

Is it possible to do this with selenium and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the matter is selenium usually interact with WebElements which can be found in HTML tree model (i.e. using xPaths or css selectors).

In your case we got only canvas, and these stars are generated by js in random way.see the screen below

[image]

So the problem is to localize these stars. If it was possible (get the location of stars) we were able to interact with these stars using [Action Builder API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html)  or some kind of robot api (robot framework).

It seems to me that quite difficult to automate this with selenium (because of random star position generation).
Regards.